# Invalid Syntaxis con pyTelegramBotAPI

Tags: python, telegram, python-import, telegram-bot

al intentar importar la libreria "telebot" me da error de syntaxis.

```
import telebot
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Instalé perfectamente pyTelegramBotAPI y TelegramBotAPI con `pip install`

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1):

El error se debe a que tanto **`async` como `await` (corrutinas) a partir de [Python 3.7 son palabras reservadas](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.7.html#changes-in-python-behavior)**. El nombre del decorador `util.async` es incorrecto si se pretende usar este paquete con Python 3.7 por la razón comentada, observando el repositorio esto está corregido en el último *commit* hace unos días:

https://github.com/eternnoir/pyTelegramBotAPI/commit/c8b2b1415745abc5278749dfc42e059bd65f332b

El paquete no ha sido actualizado en PyPi pero lo que puedes hacer es instalar directamente desde el repositorio de GitHub:

```
py -3.7 -m pip  install --upgrade --force-reinstall https://codeload.github.com/eternnoir/pyTelegramBotAPI/zip/master
```